# How can you prevent a field from being published some of the time?

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

If transforms worked in publish functions, I would be doing:

```
Items.find {}, 
  transform: (o) ->
    if o.foo_is_private
      delete o.foo
```

Comment: As a workaround, you could try two separate publications, one which gets all the ones with `foo_is_private` and excludes `foo`, and one which gets all the ones without `foo_is_private` and includes `foo`.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here, why couldn't you just do:

`Meteor.publish('items', function() {return Items.find({o.foo_is_private:false});});`

Comment: Thanks, that's less efficient than I'd like, but seems like the best solution. @Matt, I just don't want the `foo` field – I need the rest of the doc.

Comment: Related Meteor issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/821